# Could not find gem 'aws-3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I'm new to RoR and I keep getting this error when trying to install Amazon gem aws-3:

```
Could not find gem 'aws-3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

I'm using Rails 5.

The gem per se appears to successfully be installed:

```
$ gem install aws-s3
Successfully installed aws-s3-0.6.3
Parsing documentation for aws-s3-0.6.3
Done installing documentation for aws-s3 after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Added it to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'aws-3', :require => 'aws/s3'
```

On the top of the Gemfile I have listed:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `aws-s3` as `aws-3`in the `Gemfile`. It should be

`gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'`

Note: There's no gem which goes by the name `aws-3`. That is why you were getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

As told by @Arun Kumar,
you need to add [aws-s3 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-s3/versions/0.6.3) in your gemfile.Here is the [github](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3)